# How to connect a django app in heroku to mongodb atlas?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku

how can i connect my django app in heroku to mongodb atlas without installing the mLab add-on ?
i have tried to add a config var of my mongo database but it doesn't work maybe because its not a link of mLab and its a django app not nodejs. and mLab did not accept creating accounts anymore.
is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Your MongoDB hosted on Heroku?

Comment: @TarequzzamanKhan no i don't know how to do that without mLab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: its means that heroku did not make the relation with mongo it's true that it generates no errors when deploying the project but when I want to retrieve the data or connect to the admin page it takes a long time then it generates the heroku error "Application error "